# Net areas of definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given
$$
\int_{-4}^{2} f(x) dx = 5\\
\int_{-4}^{-2} f(x) dx = A\\
\int_{-2}^0 f(x) dx = B\\
\int_{0}^{2} f(x) dx = C
$$
$A$ and $C$ are areas below the $x$-axis. By interpreting definite integrals as net areas, how do I find the value of $\int_{-4}^{2} (f(x) - 2x - 3) dx$?

I tried making $-2x - 3 = g(x)$, then finding the net area of $g(x)$ from $2$ to $-4$ (which is $18.5$) then adding them together. So my final answer is $5+18.5$ units. I am not sure if I am doing it right because they have different regions above and below the $x$-axis.

Comment: Keep in mind that the two extra terms in the problem integral are inserting trapezoids and rectangles under the $  \ x-$ axis, the areas of which can be evaluated separately and then added to the integral for $ \ f(x) \ . $

Answer (score 1):

Your method is correct but your interpretation and computation of the integral seems to be wrong. Also it looks like there's more information available than you need which may be confusing. Given the problem just use what you need from what's available (a general approach).

Splitting the integral as you did, $$\int_{-4}^2f(x)-\int_{-4}^{2}(2x+3)dx=5-\left[x^2+3x\right]_{-4}^2=5-\left((4+6)-(16-12)\right)=-1.$$

From how you asked your question, make sure you read your integrals correctly, e.g. $\int_{-4}^2$ is the integral from $-4$ to $2$, so $$\int_{-4}^2f(x)dx=[F(x)]_{-4}^2=F(2)-F(-4).$$ This is probably where your misunderstanding lies.

Comment: i would assume that net area would mean |A| + |B| + |C| = $ \int_{-4}^{2} f(x) dx = 5\\ $, since its given that A and C are areas below the x-axis, am i overthinking it?

Comment: @chocopie I just had a read online and "net area" allows for negative values so the answer should be right. In every day life we only think of area as a positive value since we would not fit $-5m$ of carpet into a room. But since functions can go above and below the $x$-axis (positive and negative values), the "area" can sometimes come out as a negative. The idea of "net area" allows for this, whereas "area" does not.